# Bull queue package configuration confusion

Tags: node.js, queue

I am using bull package from npm to manage a queue "npm i bull". I got it mostly figured out and working but there seems to be something that I dont understand in the configuration.

In the configuration for a new queue theres this one:

```
 maxStalledCount: number = 1; // Max amount of times a stalled job will be re-processed.
```

this is from the reference page of their github
and then theres another configuration that you can define:

```
attempts: number; // The total number of attempts to try the job until it completes.
```

I should mention that this is relevant for failing jobs

firstly, it seems that only attempts actually determines anything, regardless of what is in maxStalledCount, the script will only follow the amount of attempts set.
for example: if i set attempts to 3 and maxStalledCount to 1, it will STILL do 3 attempts and then move it to the failed when it "ran out of attempts" 
different example: if i set attempts to 1 and maxStalledCount to 3 it will only do 1 attempt before throwing it into failed.

Can someone explain the difference? I could not find anything online.

Ultimately what I want my queue to do is attempt something up to 5 times, then move it to failed, and to be able to get all the failed jobs at a later time to retry them, how would i configure that?

added link to the reference page: https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between a 'stalled' job and a 'failed' job. According to [this note in the bull docs](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#important-notes), a job is considered stalled when:

1. The Node process running your job processor unexpectedly terminates.
2. Your job processor was too CPU-intensive and stalled the Node event loop, and as a result, Bull couldn't renew the job lock.

*maxStalledCount* is a safeguard so problematic jobs won't get restarted indefinitely.

If you are dealing with failed jobs, the *attempts* option dictates the number of attempts.

**As for your desired behavior:**

- set your *attempts* option to 5
- at some later time, gather an array of failed jobs with:

  `const failedJobs = cacheQueue.getFailed();`
- Retry the failed jobs with:

  `failedJobs.forEach(job => job.retry());`